# Android webview app loader not showing first time

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-webview

I have made a simple android webview app. Everything is working fine only my progressbar (loader) not showing when app opened. Rest of the pages when user navigate to another link then progressbar showing.

`MainActivity.java` file

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageStarted(view, url);
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
```

My problem is `onPageStarted` method. When I remove this then every page navigation display progressbar (except first time when app opened) but once I place `onPageStarted` method as above then android studio display an error like
`method does not override method from its superclass`

I am new in android and apology for this question if it is violet any policy. Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Your onPageStarted() override method do not have all the required parameters of parents class. It should be as shown below

```
   @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It solve half issue. Now all errors gone but loader/progressbar showing few seconds later. first few seconds are empty white page

Comment: Try calling your showProgress as soon as you call  webView.loadUrl(my_url)